# MySQL Correct WHERE clause with a value pair table like Wordpress usermeta

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select data from a wordpress usermeta table of some members.
I have managed to use this SQL and this works by listing all the users

```
SELECT 
wpdg_usermeta.user_id,
MAX(CASE when wpdg_usermeta.meta_key = 'firm_name' THEN wpdg_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS firm_name,
MAX(CASE when wpdg_usermeta.meta_key = 'member_name' THEN wpdg_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS member_name,
MAX(CASE when wpdg_usermeta.meta_key = 'firm_address' THEN wpdg_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS firm_address,
MAX(CASE when wpdg_usermeta.meta_key = 'firm_city' THEN wpdg_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS firm_city,
MAX(CASE when wpdg_usermeta.meta_key = 'member_email' THEN wpdg_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS member_email,
MAX(CASE when wpdg_usermeta.meta_key = 'member_directory' THEN wpdg_usermeta.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS member_directory
FROM wpdg_usermeta
GROUP BY wpdg_usermeta.user_id
```

However I want to filter only those members that agreed to appear in the member directory, so I tried to add this

```
WHERE
wpdg_usermeta.meta_key = 'member_directory' AND wpdg_usermeta.meta_value IN ('Yes')
```

However, then I get 2 rows which do have member_directory = Yes, which is correct, but all the other fields in the results except user_id are Null

also tried

```
wpdg_usermeta.meta_key = 'member_directory' AND wpdg_usermeta.meta_value = 'Yes'
```

Same result

Sorry, haven't tried selecting from a value pair table before and I'm a bit stumped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause instead:

```
having member_directory is not null
```

Comment: Thank you - haven't heard of HAVING before, HAVING member_directory = "Yes" works (because there is a No value as well)